# How do you extract a git "snapshot" retrieved from a git web interface?

Tags: git

When I download a tar gzip'd snapshot of the "archer-tromer-python" branch of gdb using [this link](http://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=archer.git;a=snapshot;h=refs/heads/archer-tromey-python;sf=tgz) and then gunzip and un-tar the file using 7-zip, I get a file 140 MB file named `archer-archer-tromey-python-b23c218`.

How are you supposed to untar this object?  Do I have the wrong usage model?  Isn't getting all the  files of a specific revision without the `.git` repository what snapshots are for?

I'm behind a firewall, which is why I'm trying to get the tar-ball instead of doing a `git clone` of the repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can download the tarball with that link, you'll be able to clone over HTTP.  I'd suggest that you do that with:

```
git clone http://sourceware.org/git/archer.git
```

... and then you can checkout the branch you're interested in with:

```
cd archer
git checkout -t origin/archer-tromey-python
```

... which will be ultimately much more useful than dealing with the tarball.

---

If you do want to use that tar archive, this may be of some use:

The archive you've linked to is actually rather strange - it's a tar archive that's been compressed gzip *twice*.  So, to unarchive it you'll need to do:

```
gunzip archer-archer-tromey-python-b23c218.tar.gz
tar xzvf archer-archer-tromey-python-b23c218.tar
```

Comment: Yeah.  I would have to set up the proxy server login details for git.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the tar-ball from that page and now I'm curious what the heck its for.

Comment: @Ross Rogers: I've updated my archive to explain how to unpack that (rather unusual) archive.

Comment: Bingo that worked, but that is rather strange.  Thanks for the help.  I'd have never figured that one out on my own.  I'm surprised by the lack of `.tar.gz` suffix on the inner file name ( or perhaps 7-Zip in windows just chops off the extension without regard to the name). The file should be named `*.tar.gz.gz`. Ultimately, it should be just a gzip'd tar-ball instead of that Russian doll trick.